# HP-Exstream tag rename

Tags: discussion, tags

HP recently sold their software Exstream to Open Text, so it is now entitled OpenText Exstream. The current SO tag is HP-Exstream, my proposed name is OpenText-Extream. What process would I need to go through to have this tag renamed?

Comment: I wonder if it might be better to make a OpenText Exstream tag and make HP-Exstream a synonym .

Comment: @NathanOliver yes that would be much better solution! because people still refer it as HP Exstream in some cases

Comment: Is there anything I can do? I am not sure how changing tags works. Do I just suggest it on meta, or is there somewhere I can formally request the change?

Comment: I would wait for meta to weigh in.  If the community decides that is what we want to do then someone with high enough score or a moderator can do this.

Comment: Awesome, I will await their response.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: Its been about a week now and it doesn't really seem like meta is for or against this, but I don't not access to make the change.